# Javascript : gauge image effect

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a 2d game using melonJS.

In my game, i have an arrow which rotate on its axis. This arrow is a png image. When i keep the left mouse button, the arrow needs to fill from yellow to red, from the base to the top. Here's an exemple :

[image: arrow filling from yellow to red]

The initial arrow is all light red, like the top of the example image. when i keep the button clicked, the arrow color should change from the bottom with a white line as a current position to the top.

How can i do this with javascript ? Is there any things embbeded in melonJS to handle this kind of trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is text based rather than code based, I'll do the same.

Here is how to draw your rotated changing-gradient arrow

- **Clear the canvas** with `context.clearRect`.
- **Rotation:** Translate to your desired center-axis coordinate around which you want to rotate. Then Rotate to your desired angle. Transformations (`context.translate` & `context.rotate`) will actually rotate the canvas itself. That way all new drawings will be translated (moved) and rotated. Note: Existing pixels will be unaffected.
- **Drawing the arrow:** Draw your arrow with path commands (`beginPath`, `moveTo`, `lineTo`, ... for each piece of the arrow). Since you have already done your transformations (translate & rotate), you don't need to try to rotate your arrow drawings.
- **Gradient fill for arrow:** Create a linear gradient (`context.createLinearGradient`) that extends through your arrow drawings. Set color stops (`context.addColorstop`) to create your desired yellow & red gradient along your arrow. Use the gradient as your `context.fillStyle` and fill your arrow path with `context.fill`.
- **Using gradients for the white indicator line** You can also use gradients to display your white indicator bar. To do this, draw your arrow and then overdraw with another gradient that is transparent at all places except your desired indicator percentage where it will be white.

  ```
  var g=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,170,0,0);
  g.addColorStop(pct-0.01,'transparent');
  g.addColorStop(pct-0.01,'white');
  g.addColorStop(pct+0.01,'white');
  g.addColorStop(pct+0.01,'transparent');
  ctx.fillStyle=g;
  ctx.fill();
  ```
- **Always clean up!** Undo your transformations. You can undo transformation by either (1) reissuing your transformation commands in reverse order and with negative arguments or (2) resetting every transformation to defaults by resetting the transformation matrix with `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`.

Put your code into a `requestAnimationFrame` animation loop and change the angle and/or the gradient to meet your design needs.

Comment: Just a note about resetting transformations, when dealing with rotate, I think one should prefer the setTransform way over the negative transforms, because of rounding issues.

Comment: @Kaiido. Yep, assuming no transformations are in-progress going into the new transformations then `context.setTransformation(1,0,0,1,0,0)` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can layer two PNG files, one with the arrow, one with the stripe, and control the position of the white stripe that sits on top of the arrow. Canvas should enable that pretty easily by default, and even more so if you're using a library.